# Creating a DbContext Interface with EF6 and Identity

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I want to create an interface for my ApplicationDbContext. However, it inherits from IdentityDbContext.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext
        : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
        ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IDbContext
```

Currently, IDbContext doesn't have any references to the IdentityDbContext tables such as Users, Roles, etc... So when I use the interface in my code anything that is accessing the Identity tables will not work because the interface doesn't include those. I've tried to add an

```
IDbSet<ApplicationUser>
```

to my ApplicationDbContext so that I can reference it in the interface but it gets confusing because ApplicationUser is a custom implementation of IdentityUser. How can I create this interface so that I can reference all the tables that my ApplicationDbContext has access to, but through the interface?

Comment: You mean something like `DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }` in your interface?

Comment: Yes. Wow, did I just overthink this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replicate the properties in your interface. For example:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    IDbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

You could also abstract the interface to make it more directly compatible with the Identity objects:

```
public interface IDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>
    where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>
    where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey, TUserRole>
    where TUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TUserRole : IdentityUserRole<TKey>
    where TUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
{ 
    IDbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
    IDbSet<TRole> Roles { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

And tweak your context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
        ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>,
    IDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
```

Comment: So when I add this, it says I'm not implementing IDbContext.Users: "IdentityContext cannot Implement IDbContext Users because it does not have a matching return type of DbSet<ApplicationUser>"

Comment: 'ApplicationDbContext' does not implement interface member 'IDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>.Roles'. 'IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>.Roles' cannot implement 'IDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>.Roles' because it does not have the matching return type of 'DbSet<ApplicationRole>'.

Comment: Also: 'ApplicationDbContext' does not implement interface member 'IDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>.Users'. 'IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>.Users' cannot implement 'IDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>.Users' because it does not have the matching return type of 'DbSet<ApplicationUser>'.

Comment: Are you using IDbSet instead of DbSet?

Comment: No, shouldI be?

Comment: I need to see your code now, the error doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Or maybe you should actually be using `IDbSet`, it's been a while since I used Identity :)

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this, but here is a drive link to the two files we're talking about: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ihw-VZKHJgv4JrB-x6c2MfGmQPabC9f2

Comment: IDbSet didn't seem to make much difference. I think it may be because ApplicationUser is inheriting from IdentityUser and the same for the other type arguments. Perhaps when it looks to IdentityDbContext to implement the interface it's not taking the custom implementations into account so it's reverting to try to match IdentityUser instead of ApplicationUser

Comment: I've made a couple of changes. Since you are using the more complex generic version of Identity objects, the generic interface needs to match that.

Comment: That worked for Users and Roles once I changed the DbSet to IDbSet. Now I just have to get it to recognize UserLogins, UserRoles, and UserClaims. Thank you so much!

Comment: I guess I don't need those in my interface since they aren't dbsets in the IdentityDbContext. Thank you again so much, I couldn't have figured it out on my own.